# Memory address of an empty object in java

Tags: java, object, memory

This may be fundamental and be voted as off-topic.
However, as a student I have to know some of the fundamentals (which may be also considered non-fundamental).

If I create a new object someObject,

```
public class foo {
    someObject bar;

    private class someObject {
        int data;

        public someObject (int value) {
            data = value;
        }
    }
}
```

without assigning any values to its field,
the memory address of the object foo seems to be null.
Within my knowledge, this does not make sense.
Isn't every object created regardless of it having data still be assigned to a memory address?
If I'm wrong (most surely), could someone elaborate more on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple:
You never create any `Object`. All you do is declare a variable. There isn't any `Object` created in the provided line - neither empty nor in any other state - , no memory allocated, except for the reference, which logically points to null.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!